# Why are there fewer question tags on Sharepoint than on other sites?

Tags: discussion, tags, stackexchange-2.0, stack-exchange

There seems to be a lot fewer tags available on the Sharepoint Stack Exchange site in comparison to other Stack Exchange sites. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: [meta.sharepoint.se]?

Comment: Niche product with a limited number of technologies.

Answer (score 3):

Tags don't exist until they've been created and applied to at least one question. If you need a tag that doesn't exist, then you should create one. If not, then there's no reason for it to exist.

On Sharepoint at the time this answer is written, [300 reputation is required to create tags](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags). Users with less than that will have to request that a moderator or another user with sufficient privileges create the desired tag, for example by leaving a comment on their question.

But on balance, sites with a more limited scope are going to have fewer tags. Stack Overflow, which covers *all* things programming-related is almost guaranteed to have a zillion different tags. Sharepoint, which only covers Sharepoint and Sharepoint-related technologies, will naturally have fewer.